# Can I attach an HTML file to a variable in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently make a variable string for the body of an email using this code.

```
 var body = "Hello " + driverArray[i] + "," +  "<br><br>Attached is your pay stub for the week of " + date + " and the subsequent schedule(s).<br><br>" + teamMessage + "<br><br>Thank you, <br>Elizabeth";}
```

I would like to replace the ending with a signature that I have saved in an HTML file. I am not sure if I can just add an HTML file to the end of this string though. How would I go about attaching the whole signature to the end of this string?

If it helps I use that variable string later like so

```
  if(htmlbody){
  mailOptions.htmlBody = htmlbody;
  }
  
  if(email){
  GmailApp.createDraft(email, subject,"",mailOptions);
```

where htmlbody is just that variable. Could I attach the HTML file here?

Comment: htmlBody is just a string so where ever you can get a string should  work

Comment: If by HTML file you literally means file, no you can't, but you can get the file content and add it to variable. What do you mean by "HTML file"? Where the file will come from and how will you be reading it?

Comment: I have a signature.html in the Google Script area. It is separate from the .gs where I have the functions. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the HTML file as string content.

```
var myHtmlFileString = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
```